# How can I ssh -X from a non-macOS machine into a macOS machine and run X11 programs displaying on the non-macOS host?

Tags: macos, catalina, ssh, x11

I have a macOS machine running Catalina.

I have also have a Linux machine, running Ubuntu 20.04.

I want to ssh from the Linux machine to the Mac by a command such as
`ssh -X user@macos-machine`.

When I try to do this, I get the error message
"X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0".
The ssh itself works, as I get a shell running on the Mac and displaying on the Linux, but programs like xeyes and xterm give errors like "Can't open display:"  (For reference, the DISPLAY variable does not get set.)

The xeyes and xterm executables exist on the macos machine, and they work if i use XQuartz.app. That is, if I am at the console of the macOS machine, xeyes and xterm work and display on the macOS machine.

My Linux machine can successfully run ssh -X to other Linux hosts, so I think I have to do something to the macOS host.

None of the machines has X11Forward turned on (or off) explicitly in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and I would like to avoid directly editing files in `/etc` if some other, more macOS -like, solution exists.

Comment: XQuartz is not needed for this (and it is not involved even had it been installed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to turn on X11 forwarding in the settings for the SSH daemon on the Mac.

In order to do that, you need to edit the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (note: this is a different file than the `ssh_config` you've mentioned in your question). Insert the following lines:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseLocalhost no
```

And then restart `sshd` and you should be able to use `ssh -X` like you want.

There's no "more macOS-like" solution for than editing the file and restarting the daemon - like you would on Linux.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much @jksoegaard  It worked exactly as you say, except that i didn't have to restart the daemon.  (Per 1488060 each new incoming connection gets a new process, which i suppose rereads the file.)  This works, and i can run xterm and xeyes, and we'll see what else.  For reference, DISPLAY is set to localhost:10.0